# Responsive Nav - Select Menu not linking

Tags: jquery, html, css, select, dropdown

I have a responsive website with a nav that changes to a select list under 800px. The code I'm using doesn't link to any pages - its lost the original links. What do I need to add to make it work?? Many thanks for any help.

```
var options = '<option selected>Navigate to...</option>';
$('nav').find('a').each(function () {
var text = $(this).text(),
    depth = $(this).parent().parents('ul').length,
    depthChar = '',
    i = 1;
for (i; i < depth; i++) { depthChar += '&#8627;&nbsp;'; }
options += '<option>' + depthChar + text + '</option>';
});
$('<select />').append(options).appendTo('nav');
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You are trying to get the select option to navigate to a page link when selected?

Comment: sorry, I didn't word it very well but yeah thats correct. Its working fine as a menu when over 800px. As soon as its under it goes to the select menu and they dont link. It was but then I wanted to add indentation to sub menu items (&#8627;&nbsp;) and I couldn't work out to incorporate both!?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the select option redirect to a link you first need to save the href from the link tag: `link = $(this).attr('href')` and then set it to the option's value: `options += '<option value="' + link +'">' + depthChar + text + '</option>';`

Now you can access that link on the select change event and set up a window redirect:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
```

Here's an example of it all together: https://output.jsbin.com/zodepedive/

I suggest that you use ids or classes for selecting elements instead of selecting them by tag so that it doesn't do this for every element on your page.